# Trying to understand the "AS" keyword in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

**"AS" keyword in Laravel framework**

I'm trying to understand this keyword "as" in the code below.

why use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Access\Gate as GateContract?

Not

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Access\Gate\GateContract.

```
    use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Access\Gate as GateContract;

    class Gate implements GateContract
    {
        use HandlesAuthorization;
```

Comment: My lack of laravel knowledge prevents me from making a full answer, but I'd guess that it is an interface or abstract class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That it's a contract is already in the namespace, so the authors thought it was redundant information. And usually, you'd just `use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Access\Gate;` and that's that.

However, since this class is *also* named `Gate`, you need to call the imported class something else - otherwise, PHP won't know to which `Gate` you refer when you call it in your code. The `as` aliases it to another name for this specific case.

Whether naming classes like this is a good or bad practice is a topic in itself, not really suitable for StackOverflow, and one which a lot of people feel surprisingly strongly about. :)

Answer (score 2):

`as` keyword in `use` is used to set alias of the original class name.

For example:

```
namespace App\Controller;

use App\Model\Book as BookModel;

class Book
{
    public function add()
    {
        $book = new BookModel();
    }
}
```

Your controller class is `Book`, and your model is `Book`. `$book = new Book();` will create object which instance of your `Book` controller, not your `Book` model. If you want to create object of your `Book` model, you have to give your `Book` model an alias, such as `BookModel`, then you can create object of your `Book` model using `new BookModel()`.